# The damage of cancer cells

Tags: dna, microbiology, cancer, mutations, dna-damage

I read about the molecular biology of cancer, and I have a mess on my head and a lot of questions.. .

My primary question is-

The damage of the cancer cells is in the dna sequence or in the gene expression(microRNAs)? or even something else?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 4):

Cancer is commonly defined as uninhibited cellular replication caused by mutations to the genome.

Genes where cancer-causing mutations have been identified are known as **oncogenes**; the COSMIC (Catalogue Of Somatic Mutations In Cancer) database lists all of the known oncogenes (547 to date - 23rd Jan 2015 - 1% of all human genes!) [[1](http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cancergenome/projects/census/)].

The *effect* of a particular mutation would be to alter in some way the expression of a gene or genes. This may be directly, for instance rendering a tumour-suppressing gene unable to fulfil its role [[2](http://www.nature.com/ncb/journal/v15/n1/full/ncb2641.html)], or indirectly, for instance by affecting epigenetic mechanisms that in turn affect expression of genes involved in cell cycle regulation [[3](http://www.nature.com/nrc/journal/v15/n2/abs/nrc3884.html)].

To my knowledge cancer is not 'caused' by just a change in expression of a gene, although it may be mediated by it. The change in expression or effectiveness of a gene (such as tumour suppressor p53) resulting in uncontrolled cell division is *caused* by mutations at the genomic level.

#### What causes the mutations?

Lots of factors can cause mutations, from chemicals (e.g. from cigarette smoke, not just restricted to the lungs either [[4](http://www.cancerresearchuk.org/cancer-info/healthyliving/smoking-and-cancer/smoking-and-cancer)]) to mistakes in the DNA replication machinery as somatic cells undergo normal cell division [[5](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/347/6217/78.short)].

The last reference there provides very compelling evidence for the reason that some tissues are more predisposed to cancer than others; tissues with higher cell turnover (and thus require more cell division) have higher incidences of cancer - see the below figure from [[5](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/347/6217/78.short)]! This figure separates "lung cancer" into two groups to show that even non-smokers have risk of developing lung cancer, but not as high a risk as those who smoke.

[image: Figure 1 from reference 5, showing the relationship between cell turnover and cancer incidence]

---

1. http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cancergenome/projects/census/
2. Muller, P.A.J.; Vousden, K.H. (2013) [**p53 mutations in cancer**](http://www.nature.com/ncb/journal/v15/n1/full/ncb2641.html). *Nat Cell Biol*. 15:2-8
3. Hamamoto, R.; Saloura, V.; Nakamura, Y. (2015) [**Critical roles of non-histone protein lysine methylation in human tumorigenesis**](http://www.nature.com/nrc/journal/v15/n2/abs/nrc3884.html). *Nat Rev Cancer*. 15:110-124
4. [Cancer research UK report on smoking and cancer](http://www.cancerresearchuk.org/cancer-info/healthyliving/smoking-and-cancer/smoking-and-cancer)
5. Tomasetti, C. & Vogelstein, B. (2015) [**Variation in cancer risk among tissues can be explained by the number of stem cell divisions**](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/347/6217/78.short). *Science* **347**, 78-81

Comment: Thanks! and what caused the mutations at the genome of a cell?

Comment: Hi @MalicOfSdom, see my edit!

Comment: No problem @MalicOfSdom. If I have answered your question please accept it. If you would rather wait to see whether others answer as well feel free, but vote up/down as appropriate, and accept an answer to help future users of this Q&A !

Comment: I would vote to your great comment but I have just 6 reputation in this site XD...and one more thing, why some tissue are less commonly to get mutation even if they divided quickly?  like muscles..

Comment: As you can see from the graph, it is not exact, but just a correlation between cell divisions and cancer - many other environmental factors affect cancer risk too, and some tissues may be more exposed than others? What makes you say muscle specifically?

Comment: Because I didn't hear about heart cancer for example...

Comment: Interesting point. No idea why cancers of the heart are so rare!

Comment: The following review rather nicely summarizes everything that encompasses cancer: [Hallmarks of Cancer: The Next Generation](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0092867411001279/1-s2.0-S0092867411001279-main.pdf?_tid=1c4f9ea8-a34b-11e4-a69d-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1422050552_b5f5b1398b90abe3482d2c1473a37d08), highly recommend reading it.